# What if a malicious validator denies to sign a new block in a shard committee in Ethereum 2.0?

Tags: signature, blocks, multisignature, sharding

In Ethereum 2.0 (Sharding Blockchain), a new block requires to be signed by all the validators as members of a committee, where blockchain has been sharded in smaller parts for supporting parallel transaction processing to enhance transaction throughput.

This way, a new block created in a time slot by a proposer, needs to be signed by all the committee's members. All the signatures then will be aggregated using **BLS Multi-Signatures With Public-Key Aggregation**.

The question is:

**What if a malicious validator denies to sign a new block in a shard committee in Ethereum 2.0 ?**

Answer (score 2):

https://ethos.dev/beacon-chain/

> Validators are rewarded when they make attestations (LMD GHOST and FFG
>   votes) that the majority of other validators agree with. ...
>
> Validators are penalized for not attesting or if they attest to a
>   block that does not get finalized. ...
>
> If a validator stands to make 10% in a year on rewards, a (honest)
>   validator stands to lose 10% if they do the worst job possible.  For
>   example, a validator that is always offline or always votes on blocks
>   that do not get finalized, will be penalized the amount that a
>   validator would be rewarded for making punctual attestations that are
>   finalized.

As long as you don't commit a slashable offense (An LMD GHOST vote is not slashable), the quote above can give you an idea of what you stand to lose.

Slashing is for a different kind of offenses, detailed in the article linked above.

Comment: I understand (honest) miners are motivated to attest valid blocks to get more rewards; however, the point is a part of your quot : **" Validators are penalized for not attesting ... "** Does not it mean that **validators are forcing to attest a block?, as otherwise they will be penalized. ** What if an honest validator wants to **forget or ignore** that 10% rewards by not signing new blocks?

Comment: There are micro penalties for this behaviour, you can see them in the phase 0 beacon chain specs: https://github.com/ethereum/eth2.0-specs/blob/dev/specs/phase0/beacon-chain.md#rewards-and-penalties-1

Comment: Additionally, if the chain is not finalizing, there will be quadratic offline penalties to ensure the offline voters will drop out in around 3 weeks (this only happens if a lot of validators don't attest).

Comment: But if penalties for not attesting new block in the committee are **micro**, cannot it encourage a malicious validator to not signing a block (for censoring that block), **as a block in order to be finalized in a shard, requires all validators' signature in a committee**. Isn't it?

Comment: A vote that is made by ⅔ of the total balance of all active validators is valid, so one defector will not change this.

Comment: It could be more effective by considering assigning validators to the shards **randomly**, where they cannot be permanent in a shard. Although, random assigning causes other complexities such as need for **inter shard transactions**

Comment: @Questioner Validators are indeed assigned to shards randomly: "random shuffling of validators, where every shard block has a (pseudo) randomly chosen committee of validators". The "Committees: Crux" section also has an example for 2 slots and validators assigned to shards randomly.  Does it help? 
...Also, your question "a block in order to be finalized in a shard, requires all validators' signature in a committee. Isn't it?" The answer is No. "...a shard block is finalized when it is crosslinked into a beacon block that is finalized".

Comment: @eth , So, then the question is **when** is a "shard block" cross-linked into a "finalized beacon block" ? under which conditions? I can ask this as a separate question if needed.

Comment: @Questioner Probably good to ask separate question. I'll think about it and research to make sure, but someone may already know.

Comment: @eth , done ! https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/82293/23024