# When is a "shard block" cross-linked into a "finalized beacon block"?

Tags: signature, blocks, multisignature, sharding, beacon-chain

In Ethereum 2.0, a shard block for being finalized needs to be linked into a finalized beacon block.

Under which conditions a "shard block" cross-linked into a "finalized beacon block"?
Having 2/3 of validators' signatures in its committee is enough? Or other additional conditions is required as well?

Comment: I would carefully say once the beacon block with the reference is finalized but it might be too early to answer as the phase 1 spec is still a moving target.